# ¿Cómo puedo configurar un proyecto de yii descargado desde un repositorio de bitbucket?

Tags: yii, bitbucket

Descargué un proyecto de un repo remoto que utiliza el framework yii. En Laravel usualmente se utiliza composer install una vez que se descarga un proyecto de un repo, pero no sé cómo configurarlo en yii. Ya intenté poniendo por consola composer install y php composer.phar install pero al momento de acceder al test de la aplicacion sólo me muestra el root del proyecto con la estructura de carpetas como muestra la imágen. Alguna solución?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El proyecto está utilizando el template `Yii 2 Advanced Project Template`.
Por default ya vienen creadas dos aplicaciónes: `backend` y `frontend`. Puedes verlas en sus respectivos directorios.

Para ingresar a cualquiera de las aplicaciones debes agregar a la `URL` `/<nombre de la aplicación>/web`.
Por ejemplo para acceder a `backend` debes agregar `/backend/web`.

En la documentación oficial de Yii2 hay información al respecto:

- [La estructura de directorios](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-directories)
- [Instalación](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation).